# "To what extent would society break down without a moral code?"

Tags: ethics, kant, utilitarianism, christianity, consequentialism

*Okay so I'm new here and I hope that this will abide by the rules and everything that the site dictates about questions.*

The title of the page is a question I formulated for a school assignment.

I have a couple of views that I have already discussed regarding it (Kantian Ethics and Consequentialism) but I am unsure about the other two I have.

I'm currently debating with myself about how Christian Ethics and Utilitarianism (deciding between Bentham's, Mill's and Singer's versions) would tackle this question.

I would like any help with this, basic ideas or any kind of comment, all would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! Usually, concrete questions work better in our format, although I don't see a direct problem with this question.

Comment: There are ambiguities in the question. If by moral code one means something spelled out and institutionalized then I imagine there would be no breakdown, as long as people "observe the code" in practice, i.e. the patterns of behavior remain social. Second, relevant behavior can be maintained through law on a threat of retribution, and while historically this did not prevent "spiritual breakdowns" it is an important factor. That general behavior does not become wholly individualistic and asocial is likely rooted in biological mechanisms beyond moral codes, even unwritten ones.

Comment: Hitchens to the rescue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iG-JLmc4Krw